# How to cross reference a property in JMESPath or JSONPath?

Tags: normalization, jsonpath, jmespath, json-path-expression

I am trying to use jmespath for my querying my json and I am trying to access a property which is at a higher level.

Below is my JSON:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "DefaultVMTypeID": "RT",
        "VM": {
            "measurements": [
                {
                    "vm": 45.62,
                    "vmString": "45.62",
                    "vmID": "RT",
                    "vmPathID": "osdu",
                    "vmTypeID": "RT",
                    "vmUnitOfMeasureID": "m"
                },
                {
                    "vm": 65,
                    "vmString": "65",
                    "vmID": "MT",
                    "vmPathID": "sample",
                    "vmTypeID": "MT",
                    "vmUnitOfMeasureID": "m"
                },
                {
                    "vm": 32,
                    "vmString": "32",
                    "vmID": "MT",
                    "vmPathID": "osduschemas",
                    "vmTypeID": "MT",
                    "vmUnitOfMeasureID": "m"
                },
                {
                    "vm": 95,
                    "vmString": "95",
                    "vmID": "MT",
                    "vmPathID": "schema",
                    "vmTypeID": "MT"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get all the measurements whose **vmId** is equal to **DefaultVMTypeID**.

I tried below query:
[properties.DefaultVerticalmeasurementTypeID, properties.Verticalmeasurements.measurements[?VerticalmeasurementTypeID]] | map(&[1].VerticalmeasurementTypeID==@[0], @)

but when applying **map** to the array @ refers to the element of the array and inside map there is no way I an access **DefaultVMTypeID**.

I have also tried transforming each element of an object.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the TS translation on JMESPath library which has 2 enhancements.

- Custom functions
- Root Value Access

https://github.com/nanoporetech/jmespath-ts

This helped me solve my problem.
[properties.Verticalmeasurements.measurements][] | [?VerticalmeasurementID==$.properties.DefaultVerticalmeasurementTypeID]

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use `$` inside expressions to access the root of the JSON.

So the JSON Path

```
$.properties.VM.measurements[?(@.vmID==$.properties.DefaultVMTypeID)]
```

should work to get all the items in the `measurements` array that match.

Comment: these are the enhancements of the original package. I was looking for actual library feature but it's not present.

Comment: No, this is raw JSON Path.  It _should_ be supported by most, if not all packages.